# OpenGL: Properly attach Texture

Tags: opengl, c++, java, graphics, jogl

### Problem:

Been trying for hours to set a simple png of a cross hair as a texture (so I could later stick in the middle of the view like a normal cross hair), without luck.

I'm coding in Java with JOGL.

P.S Also need to make the background of the texture transparent. But that's another problem.

### Code:

```
public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();  // Reset The View
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    gl.glTexParameteri ( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_REPEAT );
    texture.bind(gl);

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 0, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(0, 1);
    gl.glVertex3d(0, 1, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 1);
    gl.glVertex3d(1, 1, 0);
    gl.glTexCoord2d(1, 0);
    gl.glVertex3d(1, 0, 0);
    gl.glEnd();
}

public void init(GLAutoDrawable drawable) {
    final GL2 gl = drawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glShadeModel(GL2.GL_SMOOTH);              // Enable Smooth Shading
    gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f);    // Black Background
    gl.glClearDepth(1.0f);                      // Depth Buffer Setup
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_DEPTH_TEST);              // Enables Depth Testing
    gl.glDepthFunc(GL2.GL_LEQUAL);               // The Type Of Depth Testing To Do
    // Really Nice Perspective Calculations
    gl.glHint(GL2.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL2.GL_NICEST);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    gl.glEnable(GL2.GL_BLEND);
    try {
        String filename = "resources/misc/crosshair.png";
        texture=TextureIO.newTexture(new File( filename ),true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
    gl.glTexParameteri(GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL2.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL2.GL_LINEAR);
}
```

### Result:

[image: demonstration]

### Original png:

[image: demonstration]

### Edit

Changed code above according to comments, here's the new result:
[image]

### Another Edit

Had to add this line after glBlend, everything works after that:

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[SurvivalMachine](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/125878/46420) nailed one of your problems (you can see that the texture is repeated twice).

Your other problem (the texture is a big blob instead of a crosshair) is because you don't use transparency : some of the completely transparent pixels of your texture have a green color value (that's a common sight with optimized PNGs).

Just enable blending with `gl.glEnable(GL.GL_BLEND);`, and you'll have proper color blending in the transparent areas.

Comment: I changed the code, also tried to put GL_BLEND as you suggested (in several places). The result was always the same, updated the question...

Comment: I chose your answer because it directed me to think about blending. I actually had to add your line, plus the following: gl.glBlendFunc(GL2.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL2.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA); Now everything works!

Comment: @Jjang I'm a bit surprised that this blending function is not the default, but kudos for figuring it out :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe there's more problems, but at least this looks incorrect:

```
gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 1.0f);
```

Your texture is repeated horizontally 2 times because its wrap mode is **repeat** and the coordinates you set are over `1` (in this case `2f`). To fix this, replace `2f` with `1f`:

```
gl.glTexCoord2f(1f, 1.0f);
```

Comment: I fixed that, now no duplicates but still looks bad...